# removes folder name in url by mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a folder structure

```
/root
   /test/
     /hk/
      index.html
     /cn/
      index.html
```

I want when I visit `www.example.com.hk/test/hk/index.html`, it will show `www.example.com.hk/test/index.html` and `www.example.com.cn/test/cn/index.html`, it will show `www.example.com.cn/test/index.html`.

What should I do in .htaccess? Please description the detail. Thanks!

Comment: please also post your htaccess so we can see whats going wrong

Answer (score 0):

i think that the problem should be fixed if you use something like this in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)?/(.*)$ /$1/$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```